# How Can I create A 5 second Countdown timer with jquery that ends with a login popup?

Tags: jquery

How would i create a jquery timer that starts when a link is 'mouse-overed', Displays a 1,2,3, 4 and 5, one after the other. Then on 5 pops up a login box?

Cheers.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

How about:

```
var counter = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (counter == 5) {
        // Display a login box
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: nice concise answer - added countdown and working demo - http://jsbin.com/igoxo/3/

Comment: Don't you have to use `clearInterval(interval)`? You should call the function with the `interval` variable, not with the `counter` one.

Comment: What if I want this to run x different place in one page? How would I run this for everyone seperately?

Comment: Replace `var counter = 0;` with `var counter = 5;`, `counter++;` with `counter--;` and `if (counter == 5) {` with `if (counter == 0) {` and you are done! Now you have a real countdown, not a countup. ;)

Answer (score 21):

This is exactly the code that worked for me:

```
<p>You'll be automatically redirected in <span id="count">10</span> seconds...</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

(function(){
  var counter = 10;

  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (counter === 0) {
    //    alert('this is where it happens');
        clearInterval(counter);
    }

  }, 1000);

})();

}

</script>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://www.example.com" />
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 16):

http://jsfiddle.net/brynner/Lhm1ydvs/

HTML

```
<span class="c" id="5"></span>
```

JS

```
function c(){
    var n=$('.c').attr('id');
    var c=n;
    $('.c').text(c);
    setInterval(function(){
        c--;
        if(c>=0){
            $('.c').text(c);
        }
        if(c==0){
            $('.c').text(n);
        }
    },1000);
}

// Start
c();

// Loop
setInterval(function(){
    c();
},5000);
```

Comment: This worked great for what I needed. Thank you, Brynner.