# Creating a series of timed form submissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am interested in designing a timed quiz questions which submit themselves after 30 seconds or so. Following this other [SO request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089475/how-can-i-create-a-5-second-countdown-timer-with-jquery-that-ends-with-a-login-p) I have coded the following:

```
<script> 
var counter = 30;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Timer:"+counter
    if (counter == 0) {
    // Submit form  
    test.submit('timeout');
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

<p id="counter"></p>
```

This seems to work on most modern browsers. There is a problem however that this seems to work fine for the first question or form. I think the second form defines an additional function which causes the countdown to go twice as fast. Then the third, three times as fast, etc. Is there a way to ensure that this function is only defined once?

Thanks for any help you can provide. I am new to javascript so I apologize in advance if I have used the wrong terminology.

Comment: I think that since you are not stopping your setInterval, then all you need to do is reset counter variable to 30 secs and the rest will take care of itself. I should however mention two things: You realy shouldn't place variables on the global scope, and you should really stop your setInterval when you are finished with it, and start it again when you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call `setInterval()`, it defines an interval that will decrement the counter by 1 every second. It doesn't stop once the counter reaches 0; it just keeps decreasing it every second. Then you call `setInterval()` again, which sets up another decrement *of the same counter* every second. So now the counter gets decremented twice per second: once because of the first interval you set up and another time because of the second interval. The effect just builds up as you add more intervals.

You can see the effect in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/kwjrqm6e/)**.

The solution is just to stop the interval once the counter reaches 0, before you set up another interval. Besides, there's no need to use the same `counter` variable for all the different intervals, so you can just declare a new variable each time in a narrower scope. Narrowing the scope of variables will minimize the risk of different pieces of code interfering with each other.

```
function startCountDown(){

    // This counter is local to this invocation of the "startCountDown" 
    // function.
    var counter = 10;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {

        counter--;

        // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Timer:"+counter

        if (counter == 0) {

            // Submit form  
            console.log("Form submitted!");

            // Stop this interval so that it doesn't update the 
            // interface anymore (next interval will take care of that).
            clearInterval(interval);
            startCountDown();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

startCountDown();
```

This other **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/os5mpub3/)** shows the solution.